# Setting up multiple subdomain and multiple top level domain

Tags: dns, reverse-dns

How do I configure Bind to use multiple subdomains and multiple top level domains.
what am trying to do is this *.example.* and point this to my ipaddress.So that I can have many subdomains with as many top level domain, pointing to same server(example.com,example.org,example.net,example.de,example.fr) and on any of them i can have any numbers of subdomain. 
if the internal ipaddress of the system bind9 is install on is 192.168.1.5
how do i configure this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple TLDs are managed by bind just as multiple 2nd level domains: add them to your master configuratoin, and have a zone file for each. What ip addresses you add A records for, and how often you use the same ip address, the nameserver doesn't care.

I'm assuming you want to introduce your own, privately uses TLDs.

For hosting domains delegated to your nameservers, you won't deal with top level domains. You will only deal with the domains which are delegated to your servers. Those are subzones of TLDs.
But in fact, in terms of configuration that makes hardly any difference.